# where can I find SSL certificates on Mac OSX

Tags: ssl, osx-snow-leopard

I need an access to .k12 or .pem files for all https websites I am visiting on Mac OSx machine. Can anyone help me know the path where these files can be found.

Also, need to know a way to decrypt some packets using the key.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to get a certificate file in OSX.  One way is to export the certificates from Keychain Access.  Select **Certificates** in the **Category** (lower left) panel, choose **Select All** from the Edit menu (or hit ⌘A), and then choose **Export Items...** from the File menu (or hit ⇧⌘E).  You can export your certificates as a .p12 file or a .cer file.  The problem with this approach is you have to perform these steps periodically to keep your file in sync with the latest updates from Apple.

Another way is to install OpenSSL and use the `cert.pem` file that comes with it.  Similarly, you'll have to keep OpenSSL up to date.

Comment: It appears the OP is in need of a CA file ... OpenSSL no longer includes root CA certificates with it's distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You would simply access the tool named "Keychain Access" in the Utilities folder of your Applications directory.

Once there, you can filter each keychain to only show certificates.

As for decrypting packets using a given key, there are plenty functions doing that within the Security framework, but this question would require clarification (Language requirement etc).

Comment: But I need that specific File which I need to use in wireshark. I have accessed Keychain Access, but I need to input the file to wireshark as explained in this link: http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL

Comment: Then from Keychain utility, right click the certificate file, and export it.

Comment: One way to replace /etc/ssl/cert.pem with your certificate file. This might help !!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this too. I couldn't find the files anywhere so I thought how about exporting them.

From the `Keychain Access`:

On left pane, click on the `KEYS`. On right pane, `CTRL-Click` on the desired certificate.

The `Public key` should be exported as a `PEM` file.
The `Private Key` should be exported as a `P12` file.
The `Certificate` should be exported as a `CRT` file.

The Private key export option will as for a `passphrase` and then the user's keychain password. Upon import you will be asked for this passphrase.

NOTE: The private key, contains the public key.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to run `openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in my-csr.pem -signkey my-key.pem -out my-cert.pem`, it saves `my-key.pem` and `my-cert.pem` in the same directory where you ran the command. In my case, I ran the command at the root so it was saved there. Hope this helps someone. I spent a lot of time searching, when it was right in front of my face.